# SQL Unique values not working

Tags: sql, database, join

I'm building a query where I need to select for each country the maximum discount on the orders. So the total discount for each country is needed. And the countries must be unique.

My query is not showing unique countries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    c.Country, 
    SUM((od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice) * od.Discount) as Discount 
FROM 
    Customers c
INNER JOIN 
    Orders o ON (c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID)
INNER JOIN 
    OrderDetails od ON (o.OrderID = od.OrderID)
GROUP BY 
    c.Country, od.Discount
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Try remove "od.Discount" from group by and distinct from select.

Comment: ms-sql sorry for not mention it

Answer (score 2):

Remove `od.Discount` from `group by`  since need to find max discount per country keep only country in group by clause

Also remove `distinct` from select

```
SELECT c.Country,
       Sum (od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice * od.Discount) AS Discount
FROM   Customers c
       INNER JOIN Orders o
               ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
       INNER JOIN OrderDetails od
               ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
GROUP  BY c.Country
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the maximum discount use `max()`?

```
Select c.Country, MAX(od.Discount)
FROM Customers c INNER JOIN
     Orders o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID INNER JOIN
     OrderDetails od
     ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
GROUP BY c.Country;
```

You don't need the `distinct` in the `select` when you use `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are also grouping by Country **and Discount**, however you want to only group by country.

```
GROUP BY c.Country, od.Discount
```

becomes

```
GROUP BY c.Country
```